# Several build errors on xamarin.forms project (problems with .csproj and more)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I get the errors displayed in the image when trying to compile my Xamarin.Forms project. The problems started after i moved some files into a folder and deleted a couple of files. 
I have found several posts concerning somewhat similar issues and have tried the suggested fixes. Therefore i have checked references, unloaded and loaded he project, cleaned the code, and i even made a brand new project and manually migrated all my code from my original project to the new one. However the problems persist.

Any help fixing this would be much appreciated.

ps.  Since App.Delegate.cs and Spellbook.csproj is the only named files that is the only ones i have included. I will be happy to provide anything else that can help solve this issue.

App.Delegate.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using SpellBook;

namespace SpellBook.iOS
{
// The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
// User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
// application events from iOS.
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and 
then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary 
options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
    }
}
```

Spellbook.csproj content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.1.444934" />
          </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Condition=" '$(EnableDefaultCompileItems)' == 'true' " 
    Update="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>*.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
   </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\CharacterPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\CurrentSpells.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\MainPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Views\SpellList.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show build log, please

Comment: What non default you have in `App. Xaml`?

Comment: Aptëm : I don´t think i have acces to a build log because i am using xamarin liveplayer.

Diego: Not sure what you mean, could you clarify or point to some resource that explains what you are referring to ?